# create nested dataframe programmatically with Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to create a dataframe from a nested RDD, of course I can use the `toDF()` method, but my RDD is a case class with more than 100 fields in scala 2.10 as shown below :

```
case class User
(
  val user_id: String = "",
  valuser_name: String = ""
) extends UserExtended

class UserExtended extends Serializable 
{
  val user_adress: Option[String] = Some("")
    // 100 more
  val cards : Array[Cards] = Array[Cards]()
}
```

which makes the toDF() method useless because it doesn't take the information that is in the inherited class. But anyway, to create my dataframe, I followed what is written in the documentation and I came with this code:

```
def createDataframe(users: RDD[User])(implicit sqlContext:SQLContext) = {
  val userInfos = users.map { user =>
    val buffer = ArrayBuffer.empty[Any]
        
    buffer.append(user.idUser)
            // ... containts more than 100 fields
    buffer.append(user.userTrophies)
          
    val cards = user.cards.map { card => 
      val cardBuffer = ArrayBuffer.empty[Any]

      cardBuffer.append(card.cardName)
      cardBuffer.append(card.dps)

      Row.fromSeq(cardBuffer)
    }.toSeq
          
    buffer.append(cards)
    Row.fromSeq(buffer)
  }  

  val schema = StructType(Seq(  
    StructField("id_user",StringType,false),
    StructField("user_trophies",StringType,false),
    StructField("cards",ArrayType(StructType(Seq(
      StructField("card_name",StringType,false),
      StructField("dps",StringType,false)
    ))))   
  ))
    
  sqlContext.createDataFrame(userInfos, schema)

}
```

Unfortunately, when I run my unit test, I get this exception:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost):    
scala.MatchError: WrappedArray([Gobelin,100], [Giant,500]) (of class scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray$ofRef)
```

Which is odd because when I use the `toDF()` method on a nested RDD that I created on the shell, the nested column is a WrappedArray.

I spent days trying to find what is wrong in my code and I am still stuck with this, I will highly appreciate any help.

Comment: Your code (pretty much untouched) works for me... I added `case class Card(cardName: String, dps: String)` so it compiles (is this a correct representation of `Card`?). The MatchError means that one of the fields has a type that differs from the type you stated in the schema, unfortunately it's hard to say which one. Look for the field that can have a `[Gobelin,100]` value and verify you stated a proper type for it in the schema?